# php script showing as text

Tags: php, apache, centos

So I posted earlier regarding a cacti configuration issue, however from research it turns out to be a php/apache issue. So I am posting again to address this issue.

I have installed apache, install php, updated php to php5.5.23 as you can see here - http://noc.dediport.com/info.php

However, I have installed a script that is not interpreting the php script, it is appearing as plain text as you can see here - http://noc.dediport.com/cacti/switchporttranslate.php

The server is Centos 6.5, I have added the LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so in to my httpd.conf, however with that code when I restart apache I get the following message:

> Starting httpd: [Sat Apr 11 13:22:53 2015] [warn] module php5_module is already loaded, skipping

But that is the only php code in my conf.

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: Which code, the code for switchporttranslate.php?

Comment: you must have written <? instead of <?php

Comment: changed files to <?php from <? however now I just get a blank white page instead of the code.

Comment: Just for the record, this is a purchased whmcs/cacti addon module, they are saying it is an issue on my cacti server side. They wrote the script not myself